# How to change CSS in selenium (Full Source Code)

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, selenium

I want to change the css of a website from python to selenium.

What I have done so far has been to get the value of the CSS.

I want to change the value of this css.

The result of running the Python code below: 0px 0px 0px 270px

From 0px 0px 0px 270px
How do I change it to 0px 0px 0px 0px?

**I've tried these things, but in the end not all of them succeed.**

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.margin = '0px 0px 0px 0px';")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','0 0 0 0px')", element)
driver.execute_script("/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3hxv.png)/div[3]/div[3].setAttribute('style','0px 0px 0px 0px;');",element)

```
from selenium import webdriver
#load
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from time import sleep

# option
webdriver_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=webdriver_options, executable_path = r'chromedriver.exe')

url = 'https://www.mql5.com/en/code/29526'
driver.get(url)

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("code-content").value_of_css_property("margin")

print(element)

sleep(3333333)
```

[image]

Comment: Is codebase...css file dynamically generated?

Comment: Can you plz share the reason for which you would like to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("code-content")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.margin = '0px 0px 0px 0px';",element)
print(element.value_of_css_property("margin")) # This should return the updated margin
```